# For each loop won't print correctly

Tags: java, loops, foreach, printf

I'm not sure why this won't print out anything

```
for (int number : humidity)
         {
            if (sum < 12)
            {
             System.out.printf("%6d",humidity[sum]);
             sum++;
            }
         }
```

Humidity is taken in from a file

```
Scanner inFileHumid = new Scanner(fileNameHumid);
int [] humidity = new int[length];
```

Then is set to the array

```
while (inFileHumid.hasNextInt())
        {
                humidity[n] = inFileHumid.nextInt( );
                n++;
        }
```

and the numbers from the file are 69 67 66 64 66 69 67 67 70 69 69 70 which are the ones I'm trying to get to be printed in my for each loop

Comment: Can you paste your entire class and what it is supposed to print?

Comment: what is sum why are you using sum and not number?

Comment: What is the initial value of `sum`?

Comment: Sum was set to 0 when initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating each `number` in `humidity`, but then you ignore those values and test some unrelated `sum`. I think you want

```
for (int number : humidity)
{
  System.out.printf("%6d", number);
}
```

Or *equivalently*,

```
for (int sum = 0; sum < humidity.length; sum++)
{
  System.out.printf("%6d", humidity[sum]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a problem indexing into humidity. So this should work.

```
for (int number : humidity){
            if (number < 12) // Look at the value
            {
                System.out.printf("%6d", number);  // Print what is in the array
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sum is zero before the loop is entered, that code works.

```
    int[] humidity = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2};
    int sum= 0;
    for (int number : humidity) {
        if (sum < 12) {
            System.out.printf("%6d", humidity[sum]);
            sum++;
        }
    }
```

producing:

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     1     2
```

So for the code to fail sum must be greater or equal to 12 before the loop is entered.